# Ошибка Postgres UPDATE

Tags: sql, postgresql

Хочу апдейтить число работников d.number_employees исходя из агрегированной таблицы employees, но постгрес пишет ошибку
`SQL Error [42601]: ОШИБКА: ошибка синтаксиса (примерное положение: ",")`

Сам запрос вот:

```
UPDATE departaments AS d,
    (SELECT department, COUNT(*) AS numb
     FROM employees
     GROUP BY department) AS e
SET d.number_employees = e.numb
WHERE d.departament_name = e.department;
```

Comment: Видимо вложенный `SELECT` надо перенести в предложение `WITH`.

Comment: Какой-то дикий синтаксис. Подзапрос должен быть не в UPDATE, а в FROM, либо как коррелированный в SET. А вот повторного `departaments AS d` во FROM быть не должно. *(примерное положение: ",")* Имеется в виду запятая перед подзапросом.

Comment: FROM я убрал, погорячился, также попробовал с WITH - не помогло , все равно ругается на запятую

Answer (score 0):

У меня получилось так. Дело оказалось не во вложенном запросе, а в алиасе, по какой-то причине posgresql не взлюбил его.

```
UPDATE departaments 
SET number_employees = empl.cnt
FROM (SELECT departament, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM employees GROUP BY departament) AS empl
WHERE departament_name = empl.departament;
```